# Java constant "Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry." message

Tags: java

I keep getting these messages in java in a constant loop, which is filling up logs:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry
```

I did some searching and people were complaining that their gradle 'hangs' on this error, but my app is working fine as far as I can see without any delays, only the messages keep coming up, many of the posts were Android related as well which is not my case (I'm working on a desktop app using Intellij if that matters).

I have not yet found any concrete solutions for this problem, please advise.

Comment: If it were a problem, those logs wouldn't be at DEBUG level I'd guess?

Comment: Yeah but there is a TON of them (they pop up every couple of seconds), making my logs very hard to go through, which is an issue.

Comment: Can't you just raise your logger to INFO? I usually have my root logger set to INFO, and my.own.base.package to DEBUG when developing, INFO otherwise.

Comment: That's a last resort, but I'd still like to find the cause / disable it, it makes life difficult when trying to debug.